# Angular: How to insert an image into a <a ui-sref> that uses ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my Angular view:

```
    <a ui-sref="mystate({'stateParam1': 99, 'stateParam1': 98})" ng-bind="myCtrl.something.something.username">
    </a>

    <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{myCtrl.something.something.md5Email}}"/>
```

It works just fine. I can see a link (for my username). And it is followed by a nice Gravatar image of myself.

But I actually want my image and my username to both be in the body of the link.

I tried the following but it only showed my username, not the image:

```
    <a ui-sref="mystate({'stateParam1': 99, 'stateParam1': 98})" ng-bind="myCtrl.something.something.username"> 
      <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{myCtrl.something.something.md5Email}}"/>
    </a>
```

So how can I make this work? It seems using `ng-bind` in the `<a></a>` tag overrides any text that is inserted between the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without ng-bind

```
<a ui-sref="mystate({'stateParam1': 99, 'stateParam1': 98})"> 
  {{ myCtrl.something.something.username }}
  <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{myCtrl.something.something.md5Email}}"/>
</a>
```